# How can I find out the Root Page in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, uri

Hello i buil a WCF Webservice which should return me the root page of the website. 
Example:

Webservice Adress:

```
http://localhost/bov2/OPS.svc
```

Root Page:

```
http://localhost/bov2/
```

How can I create a string which shows me the root page?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string baseUrl = String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}/", Request.Url.Scheme,
Request.Url.Authority,
Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/'));
```

Sometimes i put it in a common class, in that case you should use this syntax

```
 public static string GetBaseUrl()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            string baseUrl = String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}/", 
            context.Request.Url.Scheme,
            context.Request.Url.Authority,
            context.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/'));
            return baseUrl;
        }
```

Comment: it works on the website but not on my webservice, it cant find "Request".

Comment: it works i just replaced httpcontext with this: HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;

Comment: I'd recommend to rewrite as `string baseUrl = String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}/",
        Request.Url.Scheme,
        Request.Url.Authority 
        Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/'));`